# Core Data Wont Persist Property Updates to Database

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm working with a subclass of NSManagedObject. Actually, it inherits from a class that inherits from a class that itself inherits from NSManagedObject (that shouldn't be a problem, right?).

**The problem**

After I make changes to the properties of the object, the object remembers the changes for its lifetime, but the changes are never saved to the database.

**How Do I Know This?**

I know this because:

- when I restart the app, the changes I've made are lost.
- telling the context to refresh the object – AFTER I've made changes to the object and told the context to save – sets the object's values back to their original state before I made the changes.
- when running the app in the simulator, I can look at the sqlite database file in the Finder, and it's modified date isn't updated when I attempt to save the context.

*Nothing is being written to the database!*

**Context**

I'm using the auto-generated delegate methods to create the store coordinator and the context. Then I'm passing the context to the view controllers in their init methods, as recommended in the docs. The store is SQLite.

I am able to successfully insert objects into the database and read them. I can even make property changes to the newly inserted object and save it successfully. I simply don't seem to be able to update object properties when the object is pulled back out of the database.

The object is fetched from the store via a relationship from another object. After making changes to its properties, I call the context's save method. However, before doing so, I call the object's isUpdated method and the context's hasChanges method, and both return false. Shouldn't they return true since I've just made changes to the object's properties but haven't saved the context?

**More**

If I call the object's committedChanges method before saving the context, however, passing in the names of the properties that I've changed, I get back the correct values of the properties. I'm not sure what this means. I would have thought that this means that the object's new property values have been successfully saved, but clearly they are not saved.

I know that the result objects is registered with a context. If I call

```
[[result managedObjectContext] refreshObject:result mergeChanges:YES];
```

the object reverts back to the original property values. This means that the context is there and that it is the same context from which the record was fetched. And it means that the new property values are never written tot he database.

**Some Code**

Here's the code where I'm poking around with all of these things. There are other places in my code where I'm making property changes, but the changes are never saved.

```
- (IBAction)statusControlChanged:(UISegmentedControl *)control {
WCAAssessmentResult *result = [self currentResult];

    /* printing the existing property values */
    if (![result.complete boolValue]) NSLog(@"result is in progress!");
    else if ([result.passed boolValue]) NSLog(@"result is passed!");
    else NSLog(@"result is not passed!");

    /* changing the property values */
    switch (control.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            NSLog(@"setting incomplete");
            result.complete = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"setting passed");
            result.passed = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
            result.complete = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
            break;
        case 2:
            NSLog(@"setting failed");
            result.passed = [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO];
            result.complete = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    /* this method always returns an empty dictionary */
    NSLog(@"%@", [result changedValues]);

    /* this method returns the values that I just set */
    NSLog(@"%@", [result committedValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"complete", @"passed", nil]]);

    /* isUpdated returns false */
    if (![result isUpdated]) {
        NSLog(@"result is not updated?! WTF!?!?");
    }

    /* hasChanges returns false */
    if (![[result managedObjectContext] hasChanges]) {
        NSLog(@"context has no changes!? WTF!?!?");
    }

    /* saving the context produces no error */
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[result managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"save failed");
        NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
    }
}
```

**A Twist**

If I create a new result object by inserting a new record into the context, I can set that object's properties and they are saved successfully. In the above code, I'm fetching the object as a member of a to-many association from another object. Is that a clue?

I'm tearing my hair out over this. What the hell could be going wrong here?

**What's NOT The Problem**

- I've logged the object's class, and it is indeed the correct class
- I've made sure that the managedObjectContext I'm saving is the same as the object's context
- I haven't made any changes to the auto-generated setter/getter methods of my managed object classes
- I've tried using the setValue:forKey: method instead of object's properties
- I've used the `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` argument to log Core Data SQL, and no SQL is logged when I update and save the object's properties

Comment: common problem? never heard of it. Put a `NSAssert(result, @"TF!");` in there

Comment: Agree - is `result` nil first? Also pass an NSError object to `save:` and interrogate its result?

Comment: updated the question. The error object is null.

Comment: it should be be ashamed of itself.

Comment: Did you subclass the `NSManagedObject`? If so, can you post that code?

Comment: I did, but I don't think the problem is there. The class files are justa uto-generated by xcode based on the model. The "complete" property is in the WCAAssessmentResult class, but the "passed" property is in one of it's superclasses, which eventually inherits from NSManagedObject. Neither of the properties are being saved. :(

Comment: I'm going to set a bounty on this question. I am going insane here trying to figure this out.

Comment: How do you know that the values are not saved? From the code you posted and the results you are reporting, it would appear that the attributes have the values you want (committedValuesForKeys) and that there are no pending updates to commit (changedValues, isUpdated, hasChanges). Perhaps you (if you are checking this manually) or your code are looking in the wrong place?

Comment: When I restart the app, the changes I've made have been lost. I'll update the question to reflect this…

Comment: Also, after I've made changes to the object and saved its context, if I call the context's refreshObject method with the object, the object's properties are set to the old values. So the new ones seem never to have been saved to context, much less to the store.

Comment: What do your core data initialization methods look like? - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator in particular? are you using the xcode templates? which persistent store container type are you using?

Comment: I'm using the template-generated methods in the app delegate. Using NSSQLiteStoreType. Thanks!

Comment: Where are the unchanging values coming from? Are they default values set in the model?

Comment: Yes, they are the defaults. Thanks, Tech.

Comment: However, as I've just updated my question to say, if I have previously edited the object before getting to this point in the app (in this case, I added some code to set the objects properties to non-default values when the objects are first inserted), the property values are successfully saved.

Comment: You never really said what the problem actually was. You said you removed some overridden method but not what methods, what these did and how that affected storing the objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not really understand your statement

```
WCAAssessmentResult *result = [self currentResult];
```

Indeed, if you are accessing a to-many relationship from an object, you should get back a set, not an object. Anyway, without seeing the code it's hard to tell. The problem you are experiencing may or may not lie there.

I would rather expect in your code something like the following snippet to access objects belonging to a to-many relationship. I assume that `yourObject` is the object you use to access the `WCAAssessmentResult` objects in the to-many relationship, which I call `results`.

```
NSMutableSet *resultObjects = [yourObject mutableSetValueForKey:@"results"];
NSPredicate *predicate = ...
[resultObjects filterUsingPredicate:predicate];

for(WCAAssessmentResult *result in resultObjects){

   // modify as needed the current result object

}

NSError *error = nil;
if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"save failed");
        NSLog(@"%@",[error description]);
}
```

Did you verify that the managedObjectContext you are using to save the object is valid (not nil) ?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. The currentResult function just returns one of the WCAAssessmentResult objects from an array instance variable of the view controller. That array is passed in with the view controller's init method, and the objects in the array are present and valid. I've tested that the managedObjectContext of the result object is correct. I even checked its persistentStoreCoordinator's store path, and it's the right database file that should be updated when I save the context…but it's not updated!

Comment: Hi, but then again, there is something you must explain better: given that the objects you want to modify are the ones in a to-many relationship, how exactly do you get the objects you put in the array that you pass to the controller? The proper way to access those objects is as shown in my code snipped. Core Data actually returns a set of objects for to-many relationships: do you create an array using the set and then retain the array?

Comment: Thanks for your persistence (pun!). I'm using a custom NSManagedObject subclass, so I access the set of values with by property name. I create the array by calling allObjects on the set. The objects are all there. I can read their values and change them in memory. The values just don't get saved when I save the context.

Comment: Ok. Assuming that your custom class is correctly reflect in your model via parent classes explicitly set in the model, I would like to know if you implemented custom validation or are using default validation instead. I suspect that the problem may be related to the validation procedure, may be you are not setting some non optional attribute or something like this. Did you already verified if this is indeed the case?

Comment: I haven't done any custom validation. I'll take a look at that issue though and report back. Thanks!

Comment: That was a good idea. I did go through my models and found some properties that were not optional. I set them to optional just to make sure that wasn't the issue and . . . no change! Still can't save. I have SQL logging on, and no SQL is executed when I save the context.

Comment: If I delete the object from its context in the same place where I'm attempting to change its properties, it is successfully deleted. the context's hasChanges method returns true. So that makes me think that it must indeed be a problem with the object's properties . . .

Comment: It's fixed. I went through my subclasses and removed some overridden methods. I'm giving you the bounty, because you prompted me in the particular investigation that resulted in the fix. When I figure out exactly what it is that I did wrong, I'll update my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas in no particular order:

I would log the class of the `result` object and make sure it is the class you think it is. Some confusion with super/sub classes could result in certain values not being saved.

If you made any alterations in the setter/getter methods in any class in the hierarchy, look closely at those methods especially if you used a `primativeValue` method. Simply leaving out `willChangeValue` and `didChangeValue` can cause changes to be invisible to the context and sometimes to the object itself.

I  would log the context you are saving as well as `managedObjectContext` property of the `result` object. Confirm they are indeed the same context.

Skip using the property accessors (the dot notation) and use `setValue:forKey` and see if that makes any difference. If so, you have an accessor problem. Likewise, you could try `setPrimativeValue:forKey` to also check for an accessor problem.

If I had to bet, I would put my money on you assigning the objects returned by a fetch to the wrong class.

Comment: I've run through these (some I already had) and updated my question to reflect it. No luck yet. Thanks though!

Comment: I'm out of ideas at this point. It's really a strange problem. You could try posting a link to the project files (if possible) and see if someone can spot something. It's not an ordinary problem and I don't think anyone can spot the issue by second hand description.